# Recaptcha always post empty on modal window

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-modal, recaptcha-v3

Recaptcha code always empty on modal...it is working without modal...i am using recaptcha v.3...
modal footer for recaptcha

in form area recaptcha field is here...

```
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_Cevap" id="recaptchaCevabi">
```

i have posting my form with thi ajax codes and my recaptcha reponse too...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit1").click(function(){
var namederfirma    = $('#namederfirma').val();
var recaptchaCevabi = $('#recaptchaCevabi').val();
var dataString      = 'namederfirma='+ namederfirma + '&recaptchaCevabi='+ recaptchaCevabi;
if( namederfirma== "" ||  recaptchaCevabi == "" )
{
alert("Bitte fülle alle Felder aus!");
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "form.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(innerHTML=result);
$('#terminform')[0].reset();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

And Recaptcha site key is here

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
grecaptcha.execute('6Lez4-EZAAAAAOg5xNHXhd3erQzFnDtMys8tTVcJ', {action: 'action_name'})
.then(function(token) {
var recaptchaCevabi = document.getElementById('recaptchaCevabi');
recaptchaCevabi.value = token;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand that 'Recaptcha always post empty',

If without modal is fine ,maybe you hava to check the step 'adding modal'.

Could you describe the change.

1. Success to get the token?
2. The hidden input field 'recaptchaCevabi' has value when you set it.

P.S. Maybe you have to hidden the site key.

Comment: i am posting recaptcha answer but it is always empty on modal box but working without modal...

Comment: Could you post the HTML with modal and  the HTML without modal, to compare both?